# A seekable one-frame FLV video (with audio)?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to generate an FLV out of an MP3 and a JPG, without uselessly looping the image and still be able to seek the audio ?

This command generates a non-seekable video:
`ffmpeg -y -i audio.mp3 -i image.jpg -r 1 -acodec copy video.flv`

and this one generates a seekable one, but with uselessly looping the image occupying both space and time:
`ffmpeg -y -loop_input -i audio.mp3 -i image.jpg -r 1 -acodec copy video.flv -shortest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only seek to keyframes. Keyframes must be I-frames, that is contain a full picture. So you will have to loop the image to create  the necessary I-frames for seeking.

You can set how often the I-frame is created by using the GOP (`-g`) option. If you really want to minimize file size, you could experiment with setting the frame-rate as low as possible and using (`-g 0`) to make sure each frame is an I-frame so the video is still seekable, e.g.

Keyframe every two seconds:

```
ffmpeg -y -loop_input -i audio.mp3 -i image.jpg -r 1/2 -g 0 -acodec copy video.flv
```

Keyframe every four seconds:

```
ffmpeg -y -loop_input -i audio.mp3 -i image.jpg -r 1/4 -g 0 -acodec copy video.flv
```

etc.

Also obviously compressing the JPG with a good compressor (like Photoshop's *Save for Web* at 60-70 quality) will also help.